# 2011 Prius AC job

Tags: repair, hvac, prius

2011 Toyota Prius AC Job

Never done one, any tips on how complicated it is.

Evidently the compressor is an electric unit?

I know the basics but do not have a charge machine, so its old school for me to do it.

Replace the pump exp valve and desiccant bag and suck it down, then statically charge as much Freon as I can from my 30lb cylinder.

But if the low pressure switch does not trip how can I introduce more Freon into the system, in other words make the compressor run manually under a low Freon condition. Its hot here in Texas right now so that may not be a problem..

Its a cya issue.

Yeah, I googled it, no YouTube videos I could find. I guess I do one.

Thanks to all who answer.

Comment: Nissan Prius? Aren't they Toyota? You shouldn't have a problem with it tripping the pressure sensor as long as you have some R134a to go into the system. I believe you dump from the low side, so it gets trapped between the bleed and the compressor, which should give it enough pressure to do its thing. You can always jump the compressor, but not something I'd suggest. I've not done any AC work on a Prius, either, but would have to assume the workings of it are pretty much the same as any other ... just a different style of driving the compressor.

Comment: I wonder where the compressor is located, I don't have any sources for Prius information.

Comment: The compressor is located next to the oil filter, seen from underneath the vehicle. You can see it in [this image](https://lusciousgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/PIC_0305.jpg).